# Destacar TextBox se o valor carregado for igual na planilha

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Em um Formulário de cadastro ao clicar em pesquisar as textbox são preenchidas.
E se algum desses TextBox tiver um valor que conste na plan1 a partir da coluna "AS" então esse TextBox tem o texto destacado (Ex. Verde). 
Consegui um código mas não esta dando certo.

**No módulo:**

```
Function ProcuraCheque(Cheque As String) As Boolean

    Dim Intervalo, Celula As Range

    Set Intervalo = Planilha1.Range("A1:B10") 'Informe aqui o intervalo onde estão os dados

    For Each Celula In Intervalo
        If Celula.Value = Cheque Then
        ProcuraCheque = True 'Verdadeiro se encontrado
        Exit For
        End If
    Next Celula

End Function

Não estou conseguindo chamr a função no evento Change ou AfterUpdate da TextBox, passando na função o valor da TextBox (tipo TextBox1.Value...). Caso ela seja verdadeira (If ProcuraCheque(Textbox1.Value)=True), o propriedade ForeColor da TextBox assume o valor vbRed, e se for Falso, vbBlack.

Private Sub TextAI1_Change()

If TextAI1.Value = "FunctionProcuraCheque" Then

    Me.TextAI1.ForeColor = &HFF0000
Else

    Me.TextAI1.ForeColor = &HFF&

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ludehenrique2cia, Veja que nesta parte do código você está comparando o "conteúdo" do TextBox com o "nome da função", a menos  que o nome da função esteja no texto do TextBox, o que vem depois do "Then" jamais será executado, somente a parte após o "Else" será executada.

```
If TextAI1.Value = "FunctionProcuraCheque" then
    Me.TextAI1.ForeColor = &HFF0000
else
    Me.TextAI1.ForeColor = &HFF& '<== SOMENTE ESTA INSTRuÇÃO SERÁ EXECUTADA!
endif
```

Creio que o que queira é comparar o conteúdo do TextBox com uma célula da planilha.